# Linux: User vs group permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, home-directory

I'm fairly new to Linux and testing around with it. I'm SSHing into the server, and I created a `testuser` while logged in as `root` ussing `adduser`. I noticed that it didn't create a home directory, so I created that as well using `mkdir`.. The directory is listed as `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root` when I do `ls -l`.

So, I changed the owner of the new home directory using `chown`. Now it looks like `drwxr-xr-x 2 testuser root`, but I don't know what to do about the `root` (group right?). I'm confused with all of these users, groups, and their permissions.

1. So, `/home/testser` belongs to user `testuser`, and it can change things in its directory but nothing else. What does that `root` indicate for the home directory?
2. In this example with `testuser`, let's say that it belongs to the group `root`. Does that mean it has the union of the privileges of `testuser` and `root` apply to this user?
3. Also, I noticed that for a new user I create, there's a new group that gets created, named the same as the name of the user. What's the purpose of this?

Comment: See, for example: http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html and http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml .

Answer (score 8):

First off, it's important you understand that when looking at a directory or file, traditional Unix permissions only know to differentiate between:

- The user
- The user's group
- Anybody else

These permissions are reflected in the `rwxrwxrwx` notation, called [modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_%28Unix%29). `r` stands for read, `w` for write and `x` for execute. Their meaning is pretty much what they're named after, only that the execute permission allows you to recurse a directory tree.

> So, /home/testser belongs to user testuser, and it can change things in its directory but nothing else. What does that root indicate for the home directory?

`root` here is the group the directory belongs to. That means that any user in the `root` group will have the permissions as indicated by the second `rwx` part of the permissions notation. For example, `drwxr-xr-x` would mean that anybody in the `root` group can only read and list that directory, but not write to it.*

> In this example with testuser, let's say that it belongs to the group root. Does that mean it has the union of the privileges of testuser and root apply to this user?

The user's privileges apply to this directory because it belongs to them. If the `testuser` also happens to be in the group `root`, then the privileges in that group would also apply. If neither is the case, only the permissions from the third part would apply.

Let's say you're on a computer science class and there's a computer where both `alice` and `bob` belong to the group `students`. Everyone of them has a home directory with `rwxr-x---` permissions, with ownership of `alice:students` or `bob:students`. That would mean any student can list and read the contents of every other student, but they cannot modify the files of their colleagues.

> Also, I noticed that for a new user I create, there's a new group that gets created, named the same as the name of the user. What's the purpose of this?

This allows you to give more flexible control over permissions. Sometimes you don't want to have a group that's shared amongst users. Especially for home folders, you don't want anybody else to even read them. This is why it's a good idea to `chown -R testuser:testuser /home/testuser`, because no group permission setting (even a `rwx` one) would be a security concern.

<sub>* Well, not exactly, since any root user can do anything, but if the group were something else, then the above would hold true.</sub>